# Is it possible to query in ADO by work item created in the current iteration? So that the query can update with each new iteration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I would like to display the results of a query that identifies the bugs created in the current iteration.  AKA "new bugs". I know this can be done by using the created date but that requires the date to manually updated for each new iteration.

Is it possible to leverage the 'current iteration' in the query?  Or some way that does require a manual update.

I have tried using only 'current iteration' but this returns all bugs in the current iteration limited by the state that I specify.  The result is not limited by when it was created.

I have tried to add a clause for created date, which works, but is not dynamic. meaning it does not increase as the iteration grows in number of days.
[image: snapshot of query]

Comment: Are you using Azure DevOps Services or an on-premise version?

Comment: There is no `@CurrentIteration.StartDate` or anything in a work item query unfortunately, so `@today-14` as a sliding window is probably closest that you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a `and/or` clause like below

[image]

I have a second drop-down list as we have different Teams, so it wants me to tell it which Team I want to bring back items for, from the `@CurrentIteration`.